# Changing VoiceOver's scrolling/paging distance on a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a screen in my app that consists of a `UITableView` with another opaque view overhanging on the top (which is also interactive). The content offset is set correctly such that the entire tableView is visible to a sighted user.

However, when using VoiceOver and paging up/down with three fingers the default scroll distance will place part of the tableView under the overhanging view, and thus prevent VoiceOver from reading part of the tableView[1].

Is there any way to change how tall a "page" is when using VoiceOver?

[1]: I know that there are still ways to cycle through all the elements, etc, but it's far easier and more discoverable for partially sighted users to skim over elements with their finger.

Comment: same problem did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityAction_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/accessibilityScroll:

Re implement that method and scroll the amount of pixels you require instead of a whole page